# Does java completableFuture has method returning CompletionStage<U> to handle exception?

Tags: java, completable-future

Does java completableFuture have thenCompose method having param with CompletionStage value type to handle exception?
like this method:

```
 public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenCompose(BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends CompletionStage<U>> var1)
```

I want to handle the result and exception and convert the result use a function A returning a completableFuture, just like :

```
CompletableFuture<V> A(V v,Throwable e);
```

and function A will call RPC. It is a async function.

CompletableFuture.handle(BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends U> var1) just convert the result, can not combine two completableFuture, can not meet my needs.

Comment: Can you make your own `thenComposeOrThrow` using `exceptionally`?

Comment: There’s no built-in method, so the closest you can get, is `handle((value, throwable) -> …return future…) .thenCompose(Function.identity())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to chain `thenCompose` with `handle` or `exceptionally`?

It should meet your needs.

Comment: I want to use the exception to do some async call, like submit a task to thread pool and also change result according to value and exception. I think "chain thenCompose with handle or exceptionally" cannot handle exception with a function with a completableFuture type return

Comment: as of JDK 12, there is CompletionStage.exceptionallyAsync (and exceptionallyAsync which takes an Executor).

Comment: If you're stuck with java8, handleAsync would work.